# How to make wordpress retrieve post title,description and thumbnail from my non wordpress database?

Tags: wordpress, post

I already have sql file call nonwordpress.sql and look like:

```html
+-------+--------------+--------------------------+-----------------+-------+
| index | name         | desc                     | thumb           | price |
| 01    | guitar ebook | learn how to play guitar | guitarebook.png | 5.00  |
| 02    | piano ebook  | learn how to play piano  | pianoebook.png  | 6.00  |
+-------+--------------+--------------------------+-----------------+-------+
```

This file have more than 1000 title,thumb,desc,price and index.
So how can make wordpress display and retrieve data as post directly from nonwordpress.sql without insert to wp posts table?
I want like:
post title is Guitar Ebook.
Thumbnail is ebook.png
Description is desc and below description is price.

Sorry about my bad english..hope can help..Thanks!

Comment: You should post the layout of your table in your question as it is much easier for us to access this way, rather than going off site to see other information - something like this may help you format it correctly https://ozh.github.io/ascii-tables/

Comment: Sorry James, now i have edit it.. please help..

Comment: this table without status,post date,user,category and all like wpdb. Any suggestion for what i must use? or some php script to run manualy? I am realy needed.. I dont see any plugin to do what i am need.. ;(

Comment: how to make title,thumbnail and description from nonwordpress.sql display as wordpress post title,thumbnail and description without insert to wp-post->post_content?

Comment: I want this because nonwordpress.sql is become update weekly to me. This make i easy and just dump the nonwordpress.sql and all will updates for the same time.. Just now, i work to find what wp php file is wordpress use to retreive post title,thumbnail and description. Please give me suggestion if you have.. ;)